# generate streaming response

Tags: chatbot, openai-api

```
app = FastAPI()

os.environ["LANGFUSE_PUBLIC_KEY"] = ""
os.environ["LANGFUSE_SECRET_KEY"] = ""
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""


LANGFUSE_SECRET_KEY = ""
LANGFUSE_PUBLIC_KEY = ""
LANGFUSE_HOST = "https://cloud.langfuse.com"

# auth_check()
handler = CallbackHandler(LANGFUSE_PUBLIC_KEY, LANGFUSE_SECRET_KEY)

CHROMA_PATH = "chroma"



@app.post("/query")
async def newQuery(query: str):
    print("query")

    query_text = query

    embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    db = Chroma(persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH,
                embedding_function=embedding_function)

    results = db.similarity_search_with_relevance_scores(query_text, k=1)
    if len(results) == 0 or results[0][1] < 0.7:
        print(f"Unable to find matching results.")
        return

    context_text = "\n\n---\n\n".join(
        [doc.page_content for doc, _score in results])
    prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(PROMPT_TEMPLATE)
    prompt = prompt_template.format(context=context_text, question=query_text)

    print("hello")
    model = ChatOpenAI(callbacks=[handler])
    response_text = model.invoke(prompt)

    sources = [doc.metadata.get("source", None) for doc, _score in results]
    formatted_response = f"Response: {response_text}\nSources: {sources}"

    return formatted_response
```

1. ```
   this is the code so how can i make it to that it response string by string
   ```

This code generates response as whole but i want to generate response as string by string same as chatGPT. As i want to get response using streaming response but did not find a way Error stats that:- 'async for' requires an object with _*aiter*_ method, got AIMessage